# c++ pointers to base class has not got derived class member functions but pointer is created with derived

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I made class that is container for pointers to base class. I can add base class objects as well as derived class objects. However when I try to use functions from derived class objects I've got compilation error "'Base' class has not member named 'name'".
Code looks like that:

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    enum Type{
        obj,
        obj1,
        obj2
    };

    class Base{
        public:
            void fun(){
                printf("I'm base\n");
            }
    };

    class Derived1 : public Base{
        public:
            void fun2(){
                printf("I'm derived1\n");
            }
    };

    class Derived2 : public Base{
        public:
            void fun3(){
                printf("I'm derived2\n");
            }
    };

    class myVector{
        private:
            vector<Base*> objects;
        public:
            void add(Type type){
                switch(type){
                    case obj:
                        objects.push_back(new Base);
                        break;
                    case obj1:
                        objects.push_back(new Derived1);
                        break;
                    case obj2:
                        objects.push_back(new Derived2);
                        break;
                }
            }

            Base* operator[](unsigned index){
                return objects[index];
            }
    };

    int main(){
        myVector vec;
        vec.add(obj);
        vec.add(obj1);
        vec.add(obj2);
        vec[0]->fun();     // ok
        vec[1]->fun1();    // error "Base" has not member named "fun1"
        vec[2]->fun2();    // error "Base" has not member named "fun2"
    }
```

It should print

I'm base
I'm derived1
I'm derived2

but I've got compilation error like in code in comments

Comment: The function names `fun2` and `fun3` are not accessible through a `Base*`.

Comment: If you want to call  functions via a base class pointer, they must be declared in the base class.

Comment: You can certainly `static_cast<Derived1*>(vec[1])->fun1()` - but that's generally a sign that you got something wrong when designing your class hierarchy.  Is there a good real-world reason you need to treat the subclasses differently, that's not solved with a virtual method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to call methods through a base-class pointer, then those methods need to be defined in the base class (perhaps as pure virtual methods).

If you know you have a subclass object, you may want to `static_cast` (or perhaps `dynamic_cast` and test), and call the method through the cast pointer.

Without any knowledge of the semantics of `fun1()` and `fun2()` it's impossible to know which alternative is best for your situation.

Here's a version that does what you want - note that `Base::fun` is declared `virtual` and the subclass implementations override it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Base {
    virtual void fun() const {
        std::cout << "I'm base" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base{
    void fun() const override {
        std::cout <<  "I'm derived1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base{
    void fun() const override {
        std::cout << "I'm derived2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Base*> vec{new Base(), new Derived1(), new Derived2()};
    vec[0]->fun();
    vec[1]->fun();
    vec[2]->fun();

    // cleanup
    for (auto e: vec)
        delete e;
}
```

Comment: Will it work if i put switch statement into operator[] and cast it there or I must cast it after calling?

Comment: If you were to cast it in your `operator[]`, that would be pointless, because it is a `Base*` again when you return it from there.  To answer your question properly requires more background on why you think you need to treat the different derived classes specially - that's usually a sign of a more serious design problem.

Answer (score 2):

C++ resolves names statically, at compile time.  You told it you have a `Base*`.  Those are the names you're allowed to use on that object, through that pointer.  Want access to the ones in `Derived` you'll have to cast.

Answer (score 2):

You just should make it a virtual function and override it in the derived class

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum Type{
    obj,
    obj1,
    obj2
};

class Base{
    public:
        virtual void fun(){
            printf("I'm base\n");
        }
};

class Derived1 : public Base{
    public:
        void fun(){
            printf("I'm derived1\n");
        }
};

class Derived2 : public Base{
    public:
        void fun(){
            printf("I'm derived2\n");
        }
};

class myVector{
    private:
        vector<Base*> objects;
    public:
        void add(Type type){
            switch(type){
                case obj:
                    objects.push_back(new Base);
                    break;
                case obj1:
                    objects.push_back(new Derived1);
                    break;
                case obj2:
                    objects.push_back(new Derived2);
                    break;
            }
        }

        Base* operator[](unsigned index){
            return objects[index];
        }
};

int main(){
    myVector vec;
    vec.add(obj);
    vec.add(obj1);
    vec.add(obj2);
    vec[0]->fun();     // ok
    vec[1]->fun();     // now it works
    vec[2]->fun();     // now it works
}
```